# Spacing in Appendix

Tags: spacing, citing, packages, appendices, appendix

I am trying to put some part of my article into the appendix. It works. However, instead of getting Appendix A, I got AppendixA without the space. How can I manage the space between 'Appendix' and 'A'.

```
\documentclass[authoryear,1p]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
    \begin{document}
    Here body
    \appendix
    \section{NLP formulation}
    \label{app_1}
    Text----
    \end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have no issues, the MWE compiles and it says 'Appendix A. NLP formulation` with spaces.

Comment: @Abutu You might have missed the code that caused the error. Otherwise, there is no problem.

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela I have other packages on the preamble. I tried to configure which exactly caused the problem. Maybe I can share the other packages as well.

Comment: Well, we are sure that the MWE you provided poses no errors. What you can do is try to comment and uncomment the packages to see which one of them is conflicting with the appendix. And then once you have found out the cause, you may update them here.

Comment: Or you might have defined the appendix in some way, maybe by using `renewcommand`.

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela Yes! now I see the problem was due to the package: 
```\usepackage[english]{babel}```
Now corrected after commenting  it.

Comment: Using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` looks ok to me.